# Change image in separate div on mouseover, image populated dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

At my wit's end again. My task is to make a dropdown menu for my company's site which populates product list items dynamically from our MySQL database and a thumbnail image of the product in a separate div onmouseover of the list item link. Most of this assignment is no problem. I have my product list items that populate my dropdown depending on parameters I set and my div and image behaves as it should on mouseover.

However, I'm stuck on figuring out how to make the onmouseover thumbnail image populate dynamically depending on the list item link that is hovered.

Here is a snippet of my static html:

```
<ul class="subcategories">        
<li><a class="thumbimg" href="PRODUCT PAGE URL" title="PRODUCT MODEL_ID" style="width:144px;height=22px;">MODEL_ID</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="showimg" width="200px" height="200px"></div>
```

I adapted the jQuery script at the following link for my purpose:
[Script at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98wuW/19/)

Here is the script as adapted:

```
var thumbimg_hover_bg = '#f6b71c'; 
var thumbimg_inactive_bg = 'none';

var showimg_thumbimg_bg = 'url("image.jpg") no-repeat';
var showimg_inactive_bg = 'none';


$(document).ready(function(){

var keep_thumbimg_highlighted = false;

$('.thumbimg').mouseover(function(){
    $('.thumbimg').css('background', thumbimg_hover_bg);
    $('.showimg').css('background', showimg_thumbimg_bg);
});
$('.thumbimg').mouseout(function(){
    if (keep_thumbimg_highlighted) {
        $('.thumbimg').css('background', thumbimg_hover_bg);
        $('.showimg').css('background', showimg_thumbimg_bg);
    } else {
        $('.thumbimg').css('background', thumbimg_inactive_bg);
        $('.showimg').css('background', showimg_inactive_bg);
    }
});
$('.thumbimg').on('click', function(){
    keep_thumbimg_highlighted = true;
});

});
```

The script works fine if I want to pull a static "image.jpg", as above. However, if I try to replace "thumbimg" (link class) and "image.jpg" with a php echo function that pulls the model ID of my product, the script breaks (yes, my .jpg images are up on my server). It could be that I am not supposed to insert php functions inside a jQuery script (still have a lot to learn, I know). However, php functions are primarily what I've used to perform dynamic actions on our website so far. (Couldn't find a way to do this in php, though.)

For reference, here is my html and script with the php functions inserted:

```
<ul class="subcategories">
<?php do { ?>
<li><a href="Product1.php?Product_ID=<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Product_ID']; ?>" class="<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?> <?php echo $row_rsProducts['ModelName']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?></a></li>
<?php } while ($row_rsProducts = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsProducts)); ?>
</ul>

var <?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_hover_bg = '#f6b71c'; 
var <?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_inactive_bg = 'none';

var showimg_<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_bg = 'url("images/<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Image']; ?>") no-repeat';
var showimg_inactive_bg = 'none';


$(document).ready(function(){

var keep_<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_highlighted = false;

$('.<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>').mouseover(function(){
    $('.<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>').css('background', <?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_hover_bg);
    $('.showimg').css('background', showimg_<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_bg);
});
$('.<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>').mouseout(function(){
    if (keep_<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_highlighted) {
        $('.<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>').css('background', <?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_hover_bg);
        $('.showimg').css('background', showimg_<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_bg);
    } else {
        $('.<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>').css('background', <?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_inactive_bg);
        $('.showimg').css('background', showimg_inactive_bg);
    }
});
$('.<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>').on('click', function(){
    keep_<?php echo $row_rsProducts['Model_ID']; ?>_highlighted = true;
});

});
```

As you can see, I thought that commanding the a class to populate dynamically with MODEL_ID and telling the javascript function to pull this name from the onmouseover link would cause it to pull the correct image. However, no dice at all.

Please help me understand what is going wrong. Sorry I'm not more savvy with this sort of thing.

Comment: Have you heard about [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: Heard about, no familiarity with. I'm willing to try anything that will work.

Comment: Ajax would really make this a lot easier to read, more dynamic and easier work with. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Also tip:
`<?php echo $var ?>` can be written `<?=$var?>`. Would make it easier to debug.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman only if short tags is enabled.

Comment: I'm perfectly willing to accept that. However, my knowledge of dynamic scripting is as yet limited to copy/pasting and adapting other written scripts I have found. It's served my purpose so far, up till now. More than willing to learn more, but time is pressing. Any chance of showing my an example of how Ajax would be scripted to perform this function??

Comment: If you don't know ajax, it's not something that would help you alot. But i recommend you read about it for your next project. Try placing the CSS `url`-attribute after the `no_repeat`. According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp), the syntax is that the `url` comes last.

Comment: I will read about that and thanks for the heads up about the CSS url attribute.
Anyone else??

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use data attribute (HTML5) in the html and let js get that data and manipulate it in the event later.

for example

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="thumbimg" href="PRODUCT PAGE URL1" title="PRODUCT MODEL_ID1" style="width:144px;height=22px;background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat;" data-image="image1.jpg" data-bgcolor="'#ffaabb">MODEL_ID1</a></li></li> 
  <li><a class="thumbimg" href="PRODUCT PAGE URL2" title="PRODUCT MODEL_ID2" style="width:144px;height=22px;background: url(image2.jpg) no-repeat;" data-image="image2.jpg" data-bgcolor="'#f6b71c">MODEL_ID2</a></li></li>
</ul>
```

and then your js just simply extract the data like:

```
$('.thumbimg').mouseover(function(){
    thumbimg_hover_bg = $(this).data('bgcolor');
    showimg_thumbimg_bg = $(this).data('image');

    $(this).css('background', thumbimg_hover_bg);
    $('.showimg').css('background', 'url('+showimg_thumbimg_bg+') no-repeat');
});
//... etc
```

so the idea is your php codes dont write your JS, but HTML only. hope you got my point.